# Wrong values stored and other

Tags: c, linux, linked-list, segmentation-fault, stack

I made this program:

**llist:**

```
typedef struct linked_list
    {
        int val;
        int n;
        struct linked_list *next;
    }llist;
```

**addelem function:**

```
void addelem(llist *list,int val)
{
    llist *tmp=(llist *)malloc(sizeof(llist)); //create new element
    tmp->val=val; //assign value to tmp
    tmp->next=NULL; //set next to NULL
  //  printf("addelem entered\n");
    if(list->next!=NULL) //if this is not the last element
    {
        addelem(list->next,val); //recursion
    }
    else
    {
    tmp->n=list->n + 1;
    list->next=(llist *)malloc(sizeof(llist)); //allocate memory
    list->next=tmp; //add to list
    }
 //   printf("addelem exited\n");
    free(tmp);
}
```

**remelem function:**

```
void remelem(llist *list)
{
    int f=0;
    if(list->n==0 && list->next==NULL)
        goto dontremove;
    if(1)
    {
    if(list->next!=NULL)
    {
        if(list->next->next==NULL)
        {
            f=1;
        }
        remelem(list->next);
    }
    else
    {
        free(list);
    }
    if(f==1)
    {
        list->next=NULL;
    }
    }
    else
    {
dontremove:
    printf("cant be removed even if the next message is 'Element removed.'\n");
    }
    //end
}
```

**show function:**

```
void show(llist *list)
{
    printf("Element number: %d\nElement Value: %d\n",list->n,list->val);
    if(list->next!=NULL)
    {
        show(list->next);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nTotal number of elems: %d\n",list->n);;
    }
}
```

**main function:**

```
int main()
{
    int i,n,ch;
    llist *list=(llist *)malloc(sizeof(llist));
    list->next=NULL;
    list->n=0;
    list->val=0;
menu: //menu label
    printf("1.Add element.\n");
    printf("2.Remove element.\n3.Show elements\n0.Exit.\n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("\nEnter value.\n");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            addelem(list,n);
            printf("Element added\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            remelem(list);
            printf("\nElement removed.\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            show(list);
            break;
        case 0:
            goto end; //end
            break;
    }
    goto menu; //show menu again
end: //end label
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1.Add element.
2.Remove element.
3.Show elements
0.Exit.
1

Enter value.
22
Element added
1.Add element.
2.Remove element.
3.Show elements
0.Exit.
1

Enter value.
4
Element added
1.Add element.
2.Remove element.
3.Show elements
0.Exit.
2

Element removed.
1.Add element.
2.Remove element.
3.Show elements
0.Exit.
3
Element number: 0
Element Value: 0
Element number: 1
Element Value: 161701936

Total number of elems: 1
```

the values are different from the ones I typed,.
My first question is that why does this happen?(probably a silly mistake) and how can i fix it to print correct value.

and here is another output:

```
1.Add element.
2.Remove element.
3.Show elements
0.Exit.
1

Enter value.
22
Element added
1.Add element.
2.Remove element.
3.Show elements
0.Exit.
1

Enter value.
23
Element added
1.Add element.
2.Remove element.
3.Show elements
0.Exit.
2

Element removed.
1.Add element.
2.Remove element.
3.Show elements
0.Exit.
1

Enter value.
22
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

In this, first I add an element, then I remove it,but if I add the element again I get segmentation fault, Can anyone explain why does this happen and how to fix it?.

And if at first I add an element and I remove it, then this is what I get:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./llist: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0855b018 ***

======= Backtrace: =========
certain memory addresses
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1969473    /path/to/this/prog
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 1969473    /path/to/this/prog
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 1969473    /path/to/this/prog
0855b000-0857c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b758e000-b75aa000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3802036    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b75aa000-b75ab000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 3802036    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b75ab000-b75ac000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 3802036    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b75c3000-b75c4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b75c4000-b7767000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3805265    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b7767000-b7768000 ---p 001a3000 08:01 3805265    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b7768000-b776a000 r--p 001a3000 08:01 3805265    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b776a000-b776b000 rw-p 001a5000 08:01 3805265    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b776b000-b776e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7782000-b7787000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7787000-b7788000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7788000-b77a8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3805277    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b77a8000-b77a9000 r--p 0001f000 08:01 3805277    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b77a9000-b77aa000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 3805277    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
bf969000-bf98a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

can anyone please tell why these errors have occured?

I use Ubuntu 12.04

Thank You

Comment: woho, that's really long.

Comment: You might consider running your program using valgrind. It will point you to some nasty issues.

Comment: Using `goto` always provokes discussions. Me I sometimes use them in a structured way to easly implemented exit points of functions without scrambling the sources. But this `dontremove` is really ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `addelem` contains a lot of errors. Check my code

```
void addelem(llist *list,int val)
{
    llist *tmp=malloc(sizeof(llist)); //create new element
    tmp->val=val; //assign value to tmp
    tmp->next=NULL; //set next to NULL
  //  printf("addelem entered\n");
    if(list->next!=NULL) //if this is not the last element
    {
        addelem(list->next,val); //recursion
        free(tmp); //not using tmp in this function
    }
    else
    {
        tmp->n = list->n + 1;
        list->next=tmp;
    }
}
```

In ypir code below statements contains lot of error

```
else
{
tmp->n=list->n + 1;
list->next=malloc(sizeof(llist)); //allocate memory
list->next=tmp; //add to list
}
//   printf("addelem exited\n");
free(tmp);
```

You are assinging new object to `next` of `list`. Then overwriting it will `tmp` object. Then deleting `tmp` object. so `list->next` will be dangling pointer

Comment: can you please explain what does the variable 'parser' do, and how can head be NULL, because I am pointing to the first element of the stack which is not NULL?

Comment: o yes. You are initializing first node @ main and not removing it. so no need of checking head with NULL. Instead of recursive functions i am using while loop with parser to parse the list till end to add the new element

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
void addelem(llist *list,int val)
{

  ...

    list->next=tmp; //add to list
  }
  // printf("addelem exited\n");
  free(tmp);
}
```

looks deadly dangerous.

First you assign `tmp` to the list's `next` member, then you free what it's pointing to.

The next time `next`is accessed the program most likley dies.